# I gave my first name and alt email to someone I don't know, will that reveal who I am?

Tags: scam, information-gathering, information-exposure

So, I wanted to get this game (to try it as it had no demo), so I went to a website, did not click on anything except the link to the Google drive folder, and then stupidly requested access to a Google Drive folder using my alt Google account. My alt account had my first name and potentially the initials of my second name, a few hours later I deleted my alt account, so am I safe?

I know when you request access to something in Google drive the owner gets an email that has the requesting account’s full name and email. I’m pretty sure they don’t have my IP address so how much trouble am I in with just giving my first and potentially initial second name and alt email (now deleted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, Google won't provide them your IP address. But whether your first name together with your initials is enough to reveal you likely depends on how broadly used this name is and whether you are remembered or not. Regarding the email it depends on where you have used the email and how easily it may be found in other places where your identity might be uncovered.

We won't be able to tell you whether or not you will be revealed to this specific person. There are too many dynamic variables.

Comment: Thanks, luckily I don't use that email for social media, and any websites I signed up for I never used my full name or provided my physical address or phone number ect., so I assume they can't harm me or do anything to me?

Comment: Also just to clarify the name Google gave was in this format:
First M(iddle) (Last). Anything in brackets were not provided.